# CMake Linking library with full path and with target_include_directories

Tags: c++, cmake

I came to a problem that I do not understand why this works in such a ways.
I am linking static libraries, specially  **libgmp-10** and   **libmpfr-4**. These are static libraries from CGAL.

This does not work:

```
list(APPEND petras_include_paths 
  #cgal
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/cgal/include"
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/cgal/auxiliary/gmp/include"
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/cgal/auxiliary/gmp/lib"
  #"C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/" #GCC
  )

 target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${petras_include_paths}>") #header for the library

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE 
  libgmp-10
  libmpfr-4
  )
```

This works:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE 
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/cgal/auxiliary/gmp/lib/libgmp-10.lib" 
  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/cgal/auxiliary/gmp/lib/libmpfr-4.lib"
  )
```

Why?
I thought that **target_include_directories** add the path to libraries, so that in **target_link_libraries** I should only need to specify the name of the library, not the full path.

Comment: Thank you, if you post this as answer, I will valide it. it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`target_include_directories` adds `#include` directories, not library search paths. `target_link_directories` adds link directories.

Before proceeding, you might want to read https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/devman_create_and_use_a_cmakelist.html

Answer (score 1):

Absolute paths should NEVER appear in `CMakeLists.txt`.

Proper way to do it is:

```
find_package(CGAL)

...
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} CGAL::CGAL)
```

As [it is documented](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/devman_create_and_use_a_cmakelist.html).

`cgal` should be just properly installed on a system.